# htaccess RewriteRule force end of execution Apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi I have written some rewrites, but from what I can tell from the logs it seems that the rules keep executing and so, although the correct result is achieved mid-execution, the final rewrite is incorrect.

Ideally I'd need to use the `[END]` flag but I can't upgrade the server software which is Apache 2.2, so I'm going to have to work around that.

I'm trying to rewrite "/wedding?url=emily-and-john-2013" to "/wedding/emily-and-john-2013".

As I'm using CodeIgniter I first need to rewrite "index.php/wedding/..." to "/wedding/...".

Here are the rules I have so far.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

    #Sends requests for /wedding/{blahblahblah} to
    #/wedding?url={blahblahblah}
    RewriteRule ^index.php/wedding/([^_]*)$ index.php/wedding?url=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here are the logs (slightly sanitised but you get the idea):

```
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b93e1c68/initial] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] add path info postfix: SRV_PATH/wedding -> SRV_PATH/wedding/emily-and-john-2013
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b93e1c68/initial] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] strip per-dir prefix: SRV_PATH/wedding/emily-and-john-2013 -> wedding/emily-and-john-2013
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b93e1c68/initial] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'wedding/emily-and-john-2013'
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b93e1c68/initial] (4) [perdir SRV_PATH/] RewriteCond: input='SRV_PATH/wedding' pattern='!-f' => matched
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b93e1c68/initial] (4) [perdir SRV_PATH/] RewriteCond: input='SRV_PATH/wedding' pattern='!-d' => matched
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b93e1c68/initial] (2) [perdir SRV_PATH/] rewrite 'wedding/emily-and-john-2013' -> 'index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013'
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b93e1c68/initial] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013 -> SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b93e1c68/initial] (2) [perdir SRV_PATH/] trying to replace prefix SRV_PATH/ with /
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b93e1c68/initial] (5) strip matching prefix: SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013 -> index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b93e1c68/initial] (4) add subst prefix: index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013 -> /index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b93e1c68/initial] (1) [perdir SRV_PATH/] internal redirect with /index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174a78/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] add path info postfix: SRV_PATH/index.php -> SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174a78/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] strip per-dir prefix: SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013 -> index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174a78/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013'
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174a78/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir SRV_PATH/] RewriteCond: input='SRV_PATH/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174a78/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] add path info postfix: SRV_PATH/index.php -> SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174a78/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] strip per-dir prefix: SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013 -> index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174a78/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] applying pattern '^index.php/wedding/([^_]*)$' to uri 'index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013'
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174a78/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir SRV_PATH/] rewrite 'index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013' -> 'index.php/wedding?url=emily-and-john-2013'
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174a78/initial/redir#1] (3) split uri=index.php/wedding?url=emily-and-john-2013 -> uri=index.php/wedding, args=url=emily-and-john-2013
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174a78/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/wedding -> SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174a78/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir SRV_PATH/] trying to replace prefix SRV_PATH/ with /
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174a78/initial/redir#1] (5) strip matching prefix: SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding -> index.php/wedding
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174a78/initial/redir#1] (4) add subst prefix: index.php/wedding -> /index.php/wedding
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174a78/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir SRV_PATH/] internal redirect with /index.php/wedding [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b917e088/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] add path info postfix: SRV_PATH/index.php -> SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b917e088/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] strip per-dir prefix: SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding -> index.php/wedding
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b917e088/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/wedding'
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b917e088/initial/redir#2] (4) [perdir SRV_PATH/] RewriteCond: input='SRV_PATH/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b917e088/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] add path info postfix: SRV_PATH/index.php -> SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b917e088/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] strip per-dir prefix: SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding -> index.php/wedding
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b917e088/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] applying pattern '^index.php/wedding/([^_]*)$' to uri 'index.php/wedding'
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b917e088/initial/redir#2] (1) [perdir SRV_PATH/] pass through SRV_PATH/index.php
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b93a1c80/subreq] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] strip per-dir prefix: SRV_PATH/wedding -> wedding
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b93a1c80/subreq] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'wedding'
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b93a1c80/subreq] (4) [perdir SRV_PATH/] RewriteCond: input='SRV_PATH/wedding' pattern='!-f' => matched
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b93a1c80/subreq] (4) [perdir SRV_PATH/] RewriteCond: input='SRV_PATH/wedding' pattern='!-d' => matched
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b93a1c80/subreq] (2) [perdir SRV_PATH/] rewrite 'wedding' -> 'index.php/wedding'
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b93a1c80/subreq] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/wedding -> SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b93a1c80/subreq] (2) [perdir SRV_PATH/] trying to replace prefix SRV_PATH/ with /
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b93a1c80/subreq] (5) strip matching prefix: SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding -> index.php/wedding
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b93a1c80/subreq] (4) add subst prefix: index.php/wedding -> /index.php/wedding
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b93a1c80/subreq] (1) [perdir SRV_PATH/] internal redirect with /index.php/wedding [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Note that on line 19 the correct URL is shown! Unfortunately it keeps running after that and some how the end result isn't correct.

Any ideas of how to change the rules to achieve the desired effect?

***EDIT***

I've just noticed that if I set the `[R]` flag for a redirect rather than a rewrite then the browser ends up pointing at the correct URL. Not sure what bearing that has on anything.

***EDIT 2***

With the `[NS]` flag added to the `index.php` rule, here are the logs:

```
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174dd0/initial] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] add path info postfix: SRV_PATH/wedding -> SRV_PATH/wedding/emily-and-john-2013
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174dd0/initial] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] strip per-dir prefix: SRV_PATH/wedding/emily-and-john-2013 -> wedding/emily-and-john-2013
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174dd0/initial] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'wedding/emily-and-john-2013'
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174dd0/initial] (4) [perdir SRV_PATH/] RewriteCond: input='SRV_PATH/wedding' pattern='!-f' => matched
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174dd0/initial] (4) [perdir SRV_PATH/] RewriteCond: input='SRV_PATH/wedding' pattern='!-d' => matched
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174dd0/initial] (2) [perdir SRV_PATH/] rewrite 'wedding/emily-and-john-2013' -> 'index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013'
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174dd0/initial] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013 -> SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174dd0/initial] (2) [perdir SRV_PATH/] trying to replace prefix SRV_PATH/ with /
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174dd0/initial] (5) strip matching prefix: SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013 -> index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174dd0/initial] (4) add subst prefix: index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013 -> /index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9174dd0/initial] (1) [perdir SRV_PATH/] internal redirect with /index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9157758/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] add path info postfix: SRV_PATH/index.php -> SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9157758/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] strip per-dir prefix: SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013 -> index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9157758/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013'
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9157758/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir SRV_PATH/] RewriteCond: input='SRV_PATH/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9157758/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] add path info postfix: SRV_PATH/index.php -> SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9157758/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] strip per-dir prefix: SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013 -> index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9157758/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] applying pattern '^index.php/wedding/([^_]*)$' to uri 'index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013'
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9157758/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir SRV_PATH/] rewrite 'index.php/wedding/emily-and-john-2013' -> 'index.php/wedding?url=emily-and-john-2013'
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9157758/initial/redir#1] (3) split uri=index.php/wedding?url=emily-and-john-2013 -> uri=index.php/wedding, args=url=emily-and-john-2013
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9157758/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] add per-dir prefix: index.php/wedding -> SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9157758/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir SRV_PATH/] trying to replace prefix SRV_PATH/ with /
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9157758/initial/redir#1] (5) strip matching prefix: SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding -> index.php/wedding
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9157758/initial/redir#1] (4) add subst prefix: index.php/wedding -> /index.php/wedding
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9157758/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir SRV_PATH/] internal redirect with /index.php/wedding [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9173fe8/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] add path info postfix: SRV_PATH/index.php -> SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9173fe8/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] strip per-dir prefix: SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding -> index.php/wedding
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9173fe8/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/wedding'
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9173fe8/initial/redir#2] (4) [perdir SRV_PATH/] RewriteCond: input='SRV_PATH/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9173fe8/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] add path info postfix: SRV_PATH/index.php -> SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9173fe8/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] strip per-dir prefix: SRV_PATH/index.php/wedding -> index.php/wedding
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9173fe8/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir SRV_PATH/] applying pattern '^index.php/wedding/([^_]*)$' to uri 'index.php/wedding'
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b9173fe8/initial/redir#2] (1) [perdir SRV_PATH/] pass through SRV_PATH/index.php
 [*/sid#b8f1e8f0][rid#b912c738/subreq] (1) [perdir SRV_PATH/] pass through SRV_PATH/wedding
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you move this rule out of the `<Directory>` or `.htaccess` context?  The passthrough subrequest seems to be the problem.

If not, try adding an `[NS]` flag to the `index.php` rule to prevent it from acting on that subrequest?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NS,L]
```

Comment: I don't think I can move it out of the `<Directory>` or `.htaccess` context as this is a virtual host, and it's not relevant to the other virtual hosts.

Comment: I've tried adding the `[NS]` flag and although the logs are cut down considerably (removing all of the `subreq` lines) the end result is the same. I'll add it to my OP.

Comment: @Josh Where exactly are these rules configured now?  Moving it to the `<VirtualHost>` context would achieve getting it out of the directory context.

Comment: @Josh Your new logs show that the last rewrite being applied sets the URL to `uri=index.php/wedding, args=url=emily-and-john-2013`, which is what you're going for if I understand you correctly?  What are you seeing that makes you think it's not working correctly -- wrong content being returned by PHP, or wrong URL in the browser's address bar?

Comment: `uri=index.php/wedding, args=url=emily-and-john-2013` is correct, unforunately the wrong content is being returned by PHP. However if I enter `.../wedding?url=emily-and-john-2013` into the address bar then the correct content is returned, which leads to believe it's a rewrite issue rather than a PHP issue.

Comment: @Josh What's the PHP using to determine what content to return? It might be looking at the URL before rewriting?

Comment: I'm using the Codeigniter REST server (https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver). The params are found using `parse_str(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY), $get);`. When does the rewrite happen such that the PHP may look at it before it happens?

Comment: @Josh Try `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` instead - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483912/php-serverredirect-url-vs-serverrequest-uri

Comment: I'm sorry my mistake, for this current issue the variables simply come from `$_GET`, although I will need to use `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` later in the project. I can't find any information on how the `$_GET` is set, is this likely to be affected in the same way?